# Swift TableViewCell Custom Style

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Hi I've been implementing custom TableViewCell with custom view , and custom style and cell'semantic to Force right to left and everything looks fine but when I Run the app all the views are stacked on each other on left hand. 
here's the screen shots before and after running the app 
[image]

and the result is :
[image]

UPDATE : Screenshots for constraints 
[image]

[image]

whats wrong with the tableview it wont stretch ? set constraint to 0 in 3 way but its not working

Comment: Show us your constraints

Comment: @MuhammadHassan I believe nothing is wrong with the constraints but wait a minute i'll add them , I have used these constraints for long and wasn't a problem ..

Comment: @MuhammadHassan added

Comment: "semantic to Force right to left" Odd thing to do. Why?

Comment: Hi Hasasan, did you also set the text orientation of the labels right to left. It seems that your labels still have a European text orientation instead of an Arabic. Otherwise the word "Detail" wouldn't have been cut at the right, but at the left.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan just wanted to try everything , I don't know why it isn't working

Comment: @MacUserT it itsnt cut , I just misstyped it

Comment: use trailing constraint for user imageview. and width, height for user. with that use tailing to details label with leading to user imageview. Hope that helps.

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski its vertically centered so it isn't needed

Comment: @Optimus the user has fixed size with constraints and as you can see in the ss I've used trailing constraint too

Comment: thats fine. Now add trailing constraint to 5 to user.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan see the new image uploaded whats wrong with it , why it wont stretch ?

Comment: @Optimus see update , I think something is wrong with this tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't judge if something's wrong with constraints from screenshot, here's what I've tried and works:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer , I recreated the whole table and cell and its working now but its not showing properly sometimes in Preview Mode in when switching to different devices but its actually working when running on device

Comment: True. Same goes on my end.

Comment: just a quick irrelevant question , how you did the spacing like that in Stackview , I mean not equal or same as weight = 1 in android

Comment: There's a spacing attribute in attribute inspector when you select stackview.

Comment: `Alignment = Center`, `Distribution = Fill`, `Spacing = 10`